# Sorting array of dictionaries using date

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array of dictionaries they look like this:

```
{
Place = "here";
Type = Any;
timeRegisted = "04-24-2017 10:42";
},

{
Place = "there";
Type = Any;
timeRegisted = "04-24-2017 09:52";
},

{
Place = "overThere";
Type = Any;
timeRegisted = "04-24-2017 05:55";
},

{
Place = "somewhere";
Type = Any;
timeRegisted = "04-24-2017 06:15";
},
{
Place = "here";
Type = Any;
timeRegisted = "04-24-2017 06:15";
},
{
Place = "overthere";
Type = Any;
timeRegisted = "04-24-2017 05:42";
},
```

But I want to sort the array base on the timeRegisted. any of you knows can I sort the array base on the time?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. We'll answer concrete questions about concrete issues. What have you tried? What's your (swift, not JSON) data structure? What issues did you run into?

Answer (score 0):

The below code will sort your array. It does make the assumption that the timeRegistered will convert to a valid date though. You should add checks for the values being returned by formatter.date being non nil

```
let array2 = array.sorted(by:{let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
    return formatter.date(from:$0.timeRegisted)! < formatter.date(from:$1.timeRegisted)!})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Alamofire & SwiftyJSON .

```
        Alamofire.request(yourURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:])
            .responseJSON { response in

                switch(response.result) {
                case .success(_):

                    var responseObject = JSON(response.result.value!).arrayValue

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"

   responseObject = responseObject.sorted(by: { [dateFormatter] (item1, item2) -> Bool in
            return dateFormatter.date(from: item1["timeRegisted"].stringValue)!.compare(dateFormatter1.date(from: item2["timeRegisted"].stringValue)!) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending
        })

        print(responseObject)
        break

                    case .failure(_):
                        print(response.result.error ?? "Response is nil")
                        break
                    }
            }
```